# Mule ESB Kernel 4.2 - gap in wrapper.conf java.additional proeprties

Tags: mule-esb

I have noticed in wrapper.conf file, that there is a gap in java.additional. properties:

```
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.max-receive-buffer-size=1048576
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.max-send-buffer-size=1048576

# Limit the Metaspace Size to protect system memory from unwanted usage
# Increase this value if you get "Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace" error
wrapper.java.additional.8=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

Is this OK? I think all additional properties starting from 8 are ignored. Also, when I add new property (18, because last active property in the original file is 17) - it is ignored as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, gaps are ok because there is a configuration option in the default wrapper.conf set to accept the gaps:

```
# Ignore gaps in additional properties sequence
wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps=TRUE
```

Ignored options are a symptom of some other problem. Are you running in Windows as a service? There is a known permissions issues about that where auto generated properties override manually set properties: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/wrapper-conf-Configuration-is-not-Updated-when-Mule-Runtime-is-running-as-a-Windows-Service

In that case you need to uninstall and reinstall the Mule service.

Comment: I don't run Mule as Windows service - just running mule.bat.

Comment: are you using the same user in all executions? if the files were created with a different user your user may not have permission to overwrite them.